# JSP page doesn't render images, but status is 200

Tags: html, jsp, bootstrap-4

I have some problems with images and links in JSP. Scripts are loaded correctly, but links to stylesheets or images are not rendered.
I've checked the network tab on Chrome debugger and seems that the images are loaded with "200 OK" status.
Here's my code:

index.jsp:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style.css">

<body>
   <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/image.png"/>
</body>
```

So like said before, bootstrap's script is loaded correctly, stylesheets and images not.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check.

1. Image is too small
2. Set `width` and `height` attributes to `img` tag
3. Add BS class `img-fluid` and check again.
4. Check whats printed here `<%=request.getContextPath()%>`. Is that path correct?
5. Try changing the path `<img src="/img/image.png"/>`

Comment: I have already tried all the things you mentioned but I still have the problem

Comment: Can you inspect via Chrome devtools the `img` `src` and copy the `src` value and open it in a new browser tab. What do you see?

Comment: I see just blank pages

Comment: That's the issue, server is not returning any valid data. Need to check the backend code.